# Error 404 when obtaining API key with Google Identity Toolkit in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am developing a Python script to obtain the API key from Google Identity Toolkit using the **firebase_admin** module and the **google-auth** library. I have followed all the instructions to enable the Google Identity Toolkit API and obtain the credentials, but I keep getting a 404 error when trying to fetch the API key.

Relevant code snippet:

```
`from firebase_admin import credentials
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import requests

def get_api_key(project_id):
    # Initialize Firebase credentials
    cred = credentials.Certificate("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json")
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

    # Get service account credentials
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
        cred.get_access_token(Request()).info
    )

    # URL to fetch the API key
    url = f"https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project_id}/webApiKey"

    # Make the request to fetch the API key
    response = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {creds.token}"})

    # Parse the JSON response and get the API key
    api_key = response.json()["apiKey"]
    return api_key

# Using the function to get the API key for the "kappmelledue" project
project_id = "kappmelledue"
api_key = get_api_key(project_id)
print(f"Obtained API key: {api_key}")`
```

I am trying to obtain the API key from Google Identity Toolkit for the specified project. I have followed all the necessary steps to enable the API and obtain the credentials properly, but I keep encountering a 404 error when attempting to retrieve the API key. I am seeking assistance to understand the potential cause of this error and find a resolution. I have also tried using different versions of the google-auth library, but the error persists.

Answer (score 1):

The error 404 indicates that the API key does not exist. This could be because you haven't turned on the Google Identity Toolkit API for your project or you typed the project ID incorrectly.

To see if the API is on, go to the [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/). Select your project, and tap on the `APIs & Services` tab. Look for `Google Identity Toolkit` in the Library section and ensure it's switched on.

If the API is active, double-check your `project ID`. The `project ID` is a special name for your project, and you'll find it in the project settings on the `Google Cloud Platform Console`.

If you've confirmed the API and project ID are right and still have problems, you might need to reach out to [Google Cloud support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub).

Here are some other things to consider:

- Make certain you're using the most recent versions of the `firebase\_admin` and `google-auth` libraries.
- Experiment with a different service account key.
- Test the script in a different setup.
- If you're using a proxy, make sure it's set up correctly.